# How to avoid en.voyages-sncf.com redirecting to uk.voyages-sncf.com?

Tags: redirection

OK, so en.voyages-sncf.com is French Railways' English language website with full functionality for train booking in France - it sells iDTGV, offers seating options etc.

uk.voyages-sncf.com is their UK subsidiary, with reduced functionality, no seat options, no iDTGV etc.

Previously, I have been able to select 'Other countries (EUR)' top right and go from the uk version to the en version, or just type in the direct url 'en.voyages-sncf.com and go there.

Now, they seem to have implemented an automatic redirect so whenever I enter 'en.voyages-sncf.com' on my UK-based PC or indeed try to select 'Other countries (EUR)' it automatically bumps me to uk.voyages-sncf.com, which I don't want.  I can't get onto en.voyages-sncf at all.

So, short of using a heavyweight solution like using a non-UK proxy server or downloading the TOR browser, is there any simple solution?

Like telling my browser to go to en.voyages-sncf, go directly to en.voyages-sncf and no other site, do not pass go, do not collect £200, do not go anywhere else, ignore all redirects and do what you're told by ME, not by those Machiavellian so-and-sos?